# Ajax comments insert LI or replace UL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, comments, dom-manipulation

I'm ajaxifying my comments feature and I'm choosing between 2 strategies. My comments list is an unordered list.

1. Replace UL in DOM with UL from response.
2. Insert last LI from response into UL in DOM.

The first option is simpler but I feel like it's not the best or right way.
If I want to use the second option how do I know which comments in the response are newer than the ones in the DOM if more than one comment was posted at the same time?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the timestamp as a variable for JS to refer.

When you load the page, your server side language will assign the timestamp of the last comment to be loaded to a javascript variable. From there on, everytime you load more comments, send the last timestamp you requested. Your server side language will check for comments that are newer than that timestamp. Make sure to update the timestamp as you send out more requests. Either by sending it as part of the response or keeping track of when you sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option 1. It is a lot simpler to implement and may actually perform faster. Make sure however do don't have any event handlers [bound](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to the LIs - they will stop to work after you update their parent UL. Use [delegates](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the comment's `UL` with latest `LI`s. **Why?** you do not have to grab all the full UL list and replace the old one. Reduce the changes that has to be made. Just grab the latest `LI` and append it at the last. `LESS WORK MORE EFFICIENT`

So far of your question, about how to know which one is the latest comment. Store timestamp as the comments are stored in the DB. While also fetching the comments for the first time, try to assign the variable holding the timestamp of the last item, then after search the database for everything that is greating the timestamp you stored, get the list and append them, then update the variable, with the latest time stamp again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your unordered list is like this:

```
<ul id="commentsList">
<li>Comment 1</li>
</ul>
```

in javascript you'll write:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "the ajax url",
  type: "GET",
  data: {//whatever data},
  success: function(r){
    //Assuming r contains the comment. 
    //(Don't send html as the response but just the comment text
    $("#commentsList").append("<li>" + r + "<li>");
  }
});
```